# How to Display Specific value when I click Specific button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When I click all the button output will be same (i.e 1).I want to display specific value of specified button for EXAMPLE:- When I click button 1 then It must display output as 1 and when I click 2 it must display output as 2.please help me.

[image]

```
<?php
    for ($i=0; $i < 10 ; $i++) { 
    echo '<br><button value="'.$i.'" class="my_remark_btn">'.$i.'</button>';
 }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.my_remark_btn').click(function(){
        remark_aftr_click();  
    });

     function remark_aftr_click(){
        var k = $(".my_remark_btn").val();  
         $.ajax({url: "my_remark_act.php",
             cache: true,
             type: "POST",
             data: {go:k},
            success: function(data_remark_mi){
                alert(data_remark_mi);
           }
         });
      }

</script>
```

my_remark_act.php:-

```
<?php echo $_POST['go']; ?>
```

Comment: `var k = $(this).val();` use this  instead of `var k = $(".my_remark_btn").val();  `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `$(this).attr("value")` like below:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.my_remark_btn').click(function(){
        var k = $(this).attr("value");
        $.ajax({url: "my_remark_act.php",
             cache: true,
             type: "POST",
             data: {go:k},
            success: function(data_remark_mi){
                alert(data_remark_mi);
            }
         });
     });
</script>
```

Example:-

```js
$('.my_remark_btn').click(function(){
  var k = $(this).attr("value");
  alert(k);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value ="1" class="my_remark_btn">1</button><br>
<button value ="2" class="my_remark_btn">2</button>
```

Comment: @Nirik Shan   Glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 2):

Try This Example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        alert(this.id); // or alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="some_id1"></button>
<button id="id2"></button>
<button id="id3"></button>
<button id="id4"></button>
<button id="id5"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('body').append("<button data-value='val' class='my_remark_btn'>val</button>")

$(document).on('click', '.my_remark_btn', function() {
alert($(this).attr('data-value'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

1. Button has no `value`.
2. Use data attribute like `data-value`.
3. Get it like `$(this).attr('data-value')` using this context for clicked button.
4. Use event delegation for dynamically added elements.

Comment: @Anant because it was input type button this time it is button element. as you can see in the php echo `<button value="'.$i.'" class="my_remark_btn">'.$i.'</button>`

Comment: Man button can have value and you can get it through .attr('value'). I have checked it at my local end

Comment: button can have value of course but is it a valid attribute for button?can you show me something so i can clarify my post @Anant

Answer (score 1):

Have a try of this

**jQuery**

```
$('.my_remark_btn').click(function(){ // when a button is clicked
    var value = $(this).value; // get the value of that specific button
    alert(value); // alert the value to the page (to make sure it is correct)
    remark_aftr_click(value);  // run function, with value as a parameter
});

function remark_aftr_click(val){  
    $.ajax({
        url: "my_remark_act.php",
        cache: true,
        type: "POST",
        data: {go: val}, // post data to Ajax with CORRECT value
        success: function(data){
            alert(data); // alert returned data
        }
    });
}
```

**Why your code was not working**:

When you were retrieving the `value` of `.my_remark_btn` before, you were only ever getting the `value` of the first element with that specific class.

**How you can get it to work**:

Instead, you need to pass the `value` as a parameter within your `function` (while using `this` as a selector to get the value of that specific button).

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery. try the below code.

```
      // this will fire for all button having class '.my_remark_btn'
      $('.my_remark_btn').click(function(){

           // using $(this) you will get the current element
            var value = $(this).val();
            console.log(value);
      });
```

In you code you are accessing value by `var k = $(".my_remark_btn").val();` , This will only return value of the `first` button with class `my_remark_btn`.